# memory address literal

Tags: c, pointers, memory, literals, memory-address

Given a literal memory address in hexadecimal format, how can I create a pointer in C that addresses this memory location?

Memory addresses on my platform (IBM iSeries) are 128bits.  C type `long long` is also 128bits.

Imagine I have a memory address to a string (char array) that is: `C622D0129B0129F0`

I assume the correct C syntax to directly address this memory location:

`const char* const p = (const char* const)0xC622D0129B0129F0ULL`

I use `ULL` suffix indicate unsigned long long literal.

Whether my kernel/platform/operating system will allow me to do this is a different question.  I first want to know if my syntax is correct.

Comment: This is what used to be the AS/400. Hell of a machine generally.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your syntax is almost correct. You don't need one of those `const`:

```
const char* const p = (const char*)0xC622D0129B0129F0ULL
```

The `const` immediately before `p` indicates that the *variable* `p` cannot be changed after initialisation. It doesn't refer to anything about what `p` points to, so you don't need it on the right hand side.

Comment: The compiler accepting it is a good place to start, but does not guarantee standards conformance.  There are many extensions implemented in compilers.  That said, yeah this looks correct.

Comment: No, this is undefined behavior. Only conversion to `void*` is supposed to give something correct and `uintptr_t` might be different from `unsigned long long` (though unlikely in this case)

Comment: Jens is wrong - the behaviour is implementation-defined, *not* undefined

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing like an address literal in C.

The only thing that is guaranteed to work between integers and pointers is cast from `void*` to `uintptr_t` (if it exists) and then back. If you got your address from somewhere as an integer this should be of type `uintptr_t`. Use something like

```
(void*)(uintptr_t)UINTMAX_C(0xC622D0129B0129F0)
```

to convert it back.

You'd have to include `stdint.h` to get the type `uintptr_t` and the macro `UINTMAX_C`.

Comment: -1: C99 only defines macros for minimum-width and greatest-width integer constants - there is no macro `UINTPTR_C()` in `stdint.h`

Comment: @Christoph: Your second assertion is correct. I'll edit my answer accordingly.